# Why when I try to clone a machine with the Node-RED on it I lose all the graphical configuration that I've made (Ubuntu Amazon Server)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, clone, node-red

I'm running an `Ubuntu Server` on an `Amazon EC2 Service`. And I'm using the `Node-RED` to create an IOT project on the cloud.

I succeeded configuring one machine in a way that it works for my project. My problem is when I clone this machine (creating an `Amazon Machine Image` of my original server and launching it as a new machine). I don't know why all the nodes that I've created on the graphical interface with the `Node-RED` disappear when I clone my Ubuntu Server. On my cloned server I just see a blank page when I access the Node-RED as if I had never created any node on the original server:

[image: My Blank Page on Node_RED]
I think this is a problem with the `Node-RED` because I'm also running a `Kibana` instance on the same server and all `Kibana's graphical configurations` are preserved with the `cloned server`.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a specific configuration on the Node-RED that I have to change to allow its graphical interface to be cloned?

OBS: I know I could just export everything that I did on the original server to my cloned server using the Node-RED import/export tools... But I'm planning to clone my original server many times, so it'd be better if everything were exactly the same when I clone the machine, without the need of manual work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node-RED stores the flow in a file in the `~/.node-red/` directory of the user running that instance, the file name is based on the host name of the machine.

e.g. on a raspberry pi the default flow file is called:

```
/home/pi/.node-red/flows_raspberrypi.json
```

So assuming that the host name gets changed when you "clone" the machine, Node-RED will not be able to find a flow file that matches the host name and as such start with an empty flow.

There are a few of ways to work round this.

- if you start Node-RED manually from the command line you can specify the flow file as the last argument: `node-red flow.json`
- if you are running Node-RED as a service then you can edit the `~/.node-red/settings.js` to include a `flowFile` key that holds the name of the flow to use.